# Rails migration: change column data type from date to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

The thing is that I have a table with a column of type date but I just use the year. How do I change it to an integer type to keep just the year? Do I need a three steps migration? And how do I make the rollback?

Comment: Leave it as a date, but just display the year.  If you don't want to bother with entering months or days, use January 1st.

Comment: I agree with @RobertHarvey, I'd leave it if it really still means the "year" of a date. You could do everything in one migration if you really wanted an integer, but a rollback can't directly recover the month and day info you'd be throwing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the other posters: you are better off storing the year as an integer if that is truly the information you want to capture. Because if you don't, and store a full date, then you're actually storing a piece of information that's a misrepresentation. I.e., it's storing a day and month and possibly some calendar metadata as well. Every time you use it you'll need to keep this in mind, and make sure that any calculations are what you really want to be doing. I.e., there are many Date and Time classes and libraries, all in use, all within Rails and Ruby.

If you only need and want the year, then store just the year. To achieve this, I'd go the easy and conservative route: make several simple migrations.

1. Add the new year column.
2. Convert the data.
3. Delete the old year column.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with some of the other posters here that you probably are better off keeping it as a date value and only displaying the year. For calculation purposes, maybe you can set all of the date values in that column to 01-01-YYYY. Then when you want to display that year in your view, do:

```
#- my_date_value=Wed, 18 Sep 2013 19:21:11 UTC +00:00
my_date_value.year
=> 2013
```

i.e.

```
<%= my_date_value.year %>
```

However, if you are determined to make this a date value, then you can do a migration like the following to convert it to a year-only integer field:

```
class ChangeThingDateToYear < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :things, :my_year_value, :integer

    # You need to tell ActiveRecord to refresh the object
    MyDatedThings.reset_column_information
    MyDatedThings.all.each do |r|
       r.my_year_value = r.my_date_value.year
       r.save!
    end

    remove_column :things, :my_date_value

    # If you want to keep the same column name
    rename_column :things, :my_year_value, :my_date_value
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your point of view and the code for the migration. Very useful! I'm actually using a date type and working with the year part only as you said, so I'm going to try the other approach now. Thanks.